# Flutter How to make a common widget between multiple web routes?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

**In Short:** How to make a common widget between routes that doesn't refresh on route change?

---

**In Long:**
Is there any way I could create a Flutter Container which covers the entire web page except the Navigation Bar and refreshes widgets inside the container according to button clicks on Navigation Bar?

What App Layout I want:

```
Material App
 |
 --Navigation Bar
 |  |
 |   -- Button 1 (Current User Screen)
 |   -- Button 2 
 |   -- Button 3
 |
 -- Container (Current User Screen: Associated With Button 1)
    |
     -- A List Of Widgets Associated with Button 1
     -- A List Of Widgets Associated with Button 2
     -- A List Of Widgets Associated with Button 3
```

**What I've Already Tried:**

- Create a Navigation Bar With 4 Buttons.
- Create routes and initial route set to 1st button content.

**Disadvantages Of What I've Tried:**

- I have to put NavigationBar() On Each Route.
- Upon Changing Route, The Refresh Of NavigationRoute() takes place.

**On Click Of Another Button From Navigation:** It refresh's the Navigation bar too. I want bar to be common widget between routes hence route change should only affect the content change in the container of root Material App.

Comment: Well, I am actually stock trying to do the same thing. Looks like it's not possible (in my case to keep a top bar)

Comment: @dieppa Since this is a early project I was working on in 21'. I wasn't able to find a solution to this except for a video that followed the near similar idea. The article and video is by [FilledStacks](https://www.filledstacks.com/post/create-and-deploy-a-flutter-web-app/) Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks! I will check that out! Well I am actually following the nested documentation described in the [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/nested-nav) It pretty fulfills my needs. :D

Answer (score 0):

I did so (not a full code but idea):

**Common widget wrapper:**

```
class ContentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  ContentPage({required this.title, required this.body});
  final String title;
  final Widget body;
}

class _ContentPageState extends ... {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Title(
      title: widget.title,
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          children: [
            SidebarWidget(),                   // contains navigation
            const VerticalDivider(width: 1),
            ContentWidget(child: widget.body), // wrapper for all content widgets
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Route handling in MaterialApp:**

```
MaterialApp(
  ...
  onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
    final uri = Uri.parse(routeSettings.name!);
    final currentPath = uri.path;
    if(currentPath == '/login') {
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => LoginPage(),
        settings: RouteSettings(name: currentPath),
      );
    }
    final pageData = getPageWidgetAndTitleForTheRoute(currentPath);
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        return ContentPage(
          title: pageData.title,
          body: pageData.builder(context),
        );
      },
      settings: RouteSettings(name: currentPath);
    );
  },
  ...
);
```

**Routing map to be use in function `getPageWidgetAndTitleForTheRoute`.**

```
final routingMap = {
  '/login': {
    'title': 'Login', 
    'widget': LoginPage(),
  },
  '/home': {
    'title': 'Home', 
    'widget': HomePage(),
  },
  ...
};
```